# Looping 3 action queries in a macro until the 4th select query returns no records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access 2007 macro named "macro_workorder_receipt" that runs a bunch of queries.  I would like someone to instruct me how to loop queries #2 and #3 and #4 , of the queries listed below, until the select query #1 does not return any records. Once the Query #1 stops returning records, then I want the macro to skip query #2 and query #3 and #4 and proceed to run the next macro  action that is not looped.  Also, if any of the queries #2, #3, or #4 fail (probably due to a database time out, because another user locked the table or grabbed my transaction ID (primary key), before I could append it to the linked table), then that failed query should rerun before proceeding to the next query (in order to prevent unmatched records).  There should also be a limit of 100 loops, so I don't overload the data base server .

1. (select query) "qryAuto_issue_primary_key_generator"
2. “qryAppend_autoissue_part_ID_to_sysadm_inventory_trans”
3. "qryMktbl_tbl_dynamic_autoissue_data_with_append_status"
4. "qryUpdt_tbl_dynamic_autoissue_data_with_append_status"

I do not know VBA, so if performing the loop is not feasible with regular macro actions, would someone be able to provide me the VBA code to copy and paste?

Comment: for what you are trying to do it sounds to me that creating a VBA macro would be more efficiently and probably more logic on execution flow.  Although the Visual macro might be easier to follow Visually.

Comment: I know you said you want to loop through the queries, but what are you doing while you loop?

Comment: the looping performs action queries on only a few records and should only take a few seconds. I would like to put a limit on the looping to not exceed more than 100 loops, in case there is corrupt data that would cause infinite looping and slow down my database server

Comment: So why not just write a query that will only update 100 records? What are you trying to accomplish? When you say loop the query, do you mean run it multiple times?

Comment: the macro usually needs to loop approximately 5  times, but sometimes I need to loop up to 50 times, if there are many records that need to be appended. The 100 loop limit is in case of the event that the query fails due to a technical difficulty e.g. if someone else grabbed my primary key or if the table is locked by another user or if there is corrupt data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is in fact using vba.

What I usually do is to nest recordsets into loops.

I can help you with the code, but you'll have to do the homework.

So, first read the Access Help (<kbd>Alt+F11</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>) regarding to "Recordsets"

Also, can you please post the SQLs of your queries?